# Method Channel in Add to App Flutter module for Android Existing App

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, flutter-method-channel, flutter-add-to-app

I want to open a discussion about MethodChannel. Can we use MethodChannel in add to app Flutter module?

I was trying to transfer data from flutter to existing android app and keep error. My suggestion is, the problem because i use add to app flutter, not from the same project in flutter.